# Can the Green Lantern ring be used to locate a nearby power battery?

Tags: dc, comics, canon, green-lantern

In the game *Injustice: Gods Among Us*, when the Justice League members are pulled into an alternate dimension, Hal Jordan sees that his ring is low on power. He then proceeds to use his power ring to locate a nearby Green Lantern power battery:

> **Green Lantern**: Ring. Where's the nearest power battery?
>
> **Power Ring**: The Ferris Aircraft facility in Coast City.
>
> **Green Lantern**: Well at least that hasn't changed... Stay low. I'll be back a-sap. [*Green Lantern goes to the Ferris Aircraft to charge his ring*] Where did you say the battery was?

Following the list of some of the ring's capabilities [here](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Ring#Powers) (or [here](https://greenlantern.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Power_Ring#Powers)), I wasn't able to find anything of that sort.

So, is this canon in the Green Lantern comics? Can the Green Lantern ring be used to locate a nearby power battery?

Comment: I notice that neither of those lists say that it can talk, either. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston “ ***A talking ring? You must be ‘Hal’lucinating, Hal*** “ -Batman

Comment: The ring could talk, if instructed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

While the main story of *Green Lantern: Legacy* (2020) isn't canon, most of its Green Lantern Corps lore from is spot on. For what it's worth, the main character (Tai) experiences exactly this when he has to recharge his ring for the first time: the ring takes him to the closest power battery, namely that of his late grandmother, stored in what only *appears* to be a storage closet.

[image: Green Lantern ring taking young Tai to the power battery]